# How to configure Filebeat on ECK for kafka input?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-stack, filebeat

I have Elasticsearch and Kibana running on Kubernetes. Both created by ECK. Now I try to add Filebeat to it and configure it to index data coming from a Kafka topic. This is my current configuration:

```
apiVersion: beat.k8s.elastic.co/v1beta1
kind: Beat
metadata:
   name: my-filebeat
   namespace: my-namespace
spec:
   type: filebeat
   version: 7.10.2
   elasticsearchRef:
       name: my-elastic
   kibanaRef:
       name: my-kibana
   config:
       filebeat.inputs:
       - type: kafka
         hosts:
         - host1:9092
         - host2:9092
         - host3:9092
         topics: ["my.topic"]
         group_id: "my_group_id"
         index: "my_index"
   deployment:
       podTemplate:
           spec:
               dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
               hostNetwork: true
               securityContext:
                   runAsUser: 0
               containers:
               - name: filebeat
```

In the logs of the pod I can see entries like following

```
log/log.go:145  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s    {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":2470,"time":{"ms":192}},"total":{"ticks":7760,"time":{"ms":367},"value":7760},"user":{"ticks":5290,"time":{"ms":175}}},"handles":{"limit":{"hard":1048576,"soft":1048576},"open":13},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"5ce8521c-f237-4994-a02e-dd11dfd31b09","uptime":{"ms":181997}},"memstats":{"gc_next":23678528,"memory_alloc":15320760,"memory_total":459895768},"runtime":{"goroutines":106}},"filebeat":{"harvester":{"open_files":0,"running":0},"inputs":{"kafka":{"bytes_read":46510,"bytes_write":37226}}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":0}},"pipeline":{"clients":1,"events":{"active":0}}},"registrar":{"states":{"current":0}},"system":{"load":{"1":1.18,"15":0.77,"5":0.97,"norm":{"1":0.0738,"15":0.0481,"5":0.0606}}}}}}
```

And nor error entries are there. So I assume that the connection to Kafka works. Unfortunately, there no data in the my_index specified above. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not able to connect to the Elasticsearch mentioned in the output.

As per docs, ECK secures the Elasticsearch deployed and stores it in the Kubernetes Secrets.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-beat-configuration.html

Comment: I can verify that the connection works, as I have tried out another input (container as in the QuickStart example) and could see the index documents in Elasticsearch. The example that you point to is for monitoring Elasticsearch itself for which you would need additional permissions. But I don't need it, I only want to index documents into an existing index.

Comment: You can check whether Filebeat is reading from the Kafka topic if the consumer group mentioned in the configuration is created. You can list all created consumer groups by running:

kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <BROKER_LIST> --list